# How can I tell if an arrow object was drawn on the previous candle when it closes?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I have been able to find the candle index of arrow objects that appear on a chart using the code below:

```
if(ObjectType(name) == OBJ_ARROW){

         if(ObjectGet(name, OBJPROP_COLOR) == Red){

            arrowTime =(datetime)ObjectGetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_TIME);
            int shift = iBarShift(_Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, arrowTime);

            Print("RED ARROW AT CANDLE ", shift);

            }

         }
```

I want to achieve something that is a bit different. How can I tell if an arrow object was drawn on the last but one candle when it closes?

Comment: what's the problem? start this process once per bar. then compare `shift==1` and that's it.

Comment: Not sure how to start this process once per bar